# Hadoop Data node is not connecting to Master Node

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have a 2 node cluster setup. one is "master-slave" and other "slave".
Name node service is up

"Slave"  node is not connecting to master node, giving the error

`slave:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/conf# tailf /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-slave.log
2014-03-02 10:43:07,816 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master-slave/192.168.1.118:54310. Already tried 4 time(s).
2014-03-02 10:43:08,817 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master-slave/192.168.1.118:54310. Already tried 5 time(s).
2014-03-02 10:43:09,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master-slave/192.168.1.118:54310. Already tried 6 time(s).
2014-03-02 10:43:10,821 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master-slave/192.168.1.118:54310. Already tried 7 time(s).`

a). 
`master-slave:/usr/lib/hadoop/conf# lsof -i:54310
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    3080 hdfs   62u  IPv4  22507      0t0  TCP master-slave:54310 (LISTEN)`

b). On Slave in core-site.xml

`<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://master-slave:54310</value>
        <description>The name of the default file system.  Either the
            literal string "local" or a host:port for NDFS.</description>
        <final>true</final>
</property>`

c). master node /etc/hosts(same in slave node)

`master-slave:/usr/lib/hadoop/conf# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   master-slave
192.168.1.118  master-slave
192.168.1.120   slave`

d). I have disabled the IPV6.

e). I'm not able to telnet to port 54310 from slave to master-slave but able to on port 22

Looks very weird, please help me in fixing the problem. I have made every changes I know but no luck.

Comment: Post output of `netstat -nlp` from master

Comment: Any other error in log??? And it's the first time you are starting the hadoop cluster or its running before this happens?

Comment: thanks for reply.
here is the ouput of netstat  http://pastebin.com/btxMexzr

@VikasHardia no other errors in the logs. This is first time I'm starting this cluster.  FYI also added the nodes in slaves file(config file)

Comment: Comment the 127.0.1.1 master-slave on both the machines in hosts file  and try again

Comment: @VikasHardia ..  "127.0.1.1 master-slave" was there only in "master-slave" node. I removed it and started it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For future reference here is problem due to hosts file edit the file and remove this entry

```
127.0.1.1 master-slave
```

After removing it works fine.